# Creating a pattern from a CSS-resized image and drawing it on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm working on an app that allows the user to select an image and define a custom clipping region for that image. The user can place blue dots on the canvas containing the image, which will represent the clipping path. These points are stored in the `coordinates` array. This is the function that clips the image to the selected area:

```
function crop()
{
  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
  for(let i=1; i<coordinates.length; i++)
  {
    ctx.lineTo(coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y);
  }
  ctx.lineTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.clip();

  //redraw the image in the cropped area
  let pattern = ctx.createPattern(image, "repeat");
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.closePath();
}
```

This works perfectly fine when I let the image keep its natural dimensions (in this case 1200x600):[image]

But if I give the image `max-height` and `max-width` properties, each set to 80vmin, the cropping stops working correctly:[image]

Instead of cropping the image around the eye area, like in the previous image, it clips a different part of the image to the selected area.

I suspect `createPattern` is for some reason not loading the image properly, with its updated dimensions. So I tried passing it a new canvas object (which is basically a copy of the canvas I'm working on in its original form, with the resized image painted on and nothing else) instead of the image itself, but that didn't seem to work either, I was getting the same result. Is there anything else I could try?

Update: here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7f5reg6v/) containing the whole code

```js
const image = document.getElementById("pic");

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//draw the image on the canvas
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

//get mouse coordinates
let coordinates = [];
canvas.onclick = function clickEvent(e)
{
  let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  let y = e.clientY - rect.top;

  let point = {
    "x": x,
    "y": y
  };
  coordinates.push(point);

  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
}

//debugging
console.log(coordinates);

//crop the image
function crop()
{
  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
  for(let i=1; i<coordinates.length; i++)
  {
    ctx.lineTo(coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y);
  }
  ctx.lineTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.clip();

  //redraw the image in the cropped area
  let pattern = ctx.createPattern(image, "repeat");
  ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.closePath();
}

function save()
{
  let newCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');

  //get new dimensions
  let top = canvas.height;
  let left = canvas.width;
  let right = -canvas.width;
  let bottom = -canvas.height;
  for(let i=0; i<coordinates.length; i++)
  {
    if(coordinates[i].y < top)
      top = coordinates[i].y;
    if(coordinates[i].x < left)
      left = coordinates[i].x;
    if(coordinates[i].x > right)
      right = coordinates[i].x;
    if(coordinates[i].y > bottom)
      bottom = coordinates[i].y;
  }

  newCanvas.width = right-left;
  newCanvas.height = bottom-top;

  //save the new image
  newCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(canvas, left, top, newCanvas.width, newCanvas.height, 0, 0, newCanvas.width, newCanvas.height);

  let downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = "crop.png";
  downloadLink.href = newCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  downloadLink.click();
}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.image-div img {
  max-width: 80vmin;
  max-height: 80vmin;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.canvas-div {
  margin-top: 240px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Image:</h1>
    <div class="image-div">
      <img id="pic" src="https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/07/Helping-your-new-cat-or-kitten-settle-in-1.png">
    </div>

    <div class="canvas-div">
      <h1>Canvas:</h1>
      <canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid blue;"></canvas>
    </div>

    <!-- for exporting the final result -->
    <canvas id="canvas2" style="display: none;"></canvas>

    <button onclick="crop()">Crop</button>
    <button onclick="save()">Save</button>
    <br><br><br>

    <!-- script -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to calculate the factor: `window.innerWidth * 0.8 / image.naturalWidth` should be the one you need. Now multiply every coordinate by that factor.

Comment: Multiplying the coordinates doesn't seem to work, it just selects a different part of the image to crop, but the resulting image itself is still oversized

Comment: You can clearly see that the correct factor will fix this: https://i.imgur.com/k3hmwJa.png It's just a matter of finding it.

Comment: I tried to play around with your Fiddle, but it's only displaying an image and two buttons. Can you provide steps to reproduce the problem or update your JSFiddle with working controls?

Comment: @LajosArpad there should be a canvas right above the buttons, it probably just failed to load properly. Is it not showing up even after refreshing the page?

Answer (score 1):

Before reading the explanation try the following:

```
  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
  for(let i=1; i<coordinates.length; i++)
  {
    ctx.lineTo(coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y);
  }
  ctx.lineTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.clip();

  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.restore();
```

You will see that it does an invert cropping, that is, it clears the points you want to not clear and preserves the points you wanted to clear. So, to solve your problem, assuming that the crop will be a convex shape, you need the following:

- get all the lines involved
- create a polygon of the "outside" of the polygons
- clear

Since you can have many different types of shapes and they can be convex or concave alike, it would be far-fetched for the purpose of a stackoverflow answer to implement the full logic, but this is how you can do it relatively easily:

1. Make sure that the lines are continuous, so if you draw the lines by hand from coordinates[0] to coordinates[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcC3p.png) and then coordinates[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcC3p.png) to coordinates[2], etc. then you will end up drawing the correct polygon (so each line between coordinates[i-1] and coordinates[i]) is a side of your polygon rather than a diagonal.
2. `moveTo` coordinates[0] and have a lineto for all coordinates, almost like you did, except for the very last one. So, you are effectively almost drawing the polygon except the very last line.
3. continue with lineto to a side of the canvas (careful though, not to cross the internal of the polygon) and then to all the edges of the canvas (the corners), so you are effectively defining a polygon that's a. outside your polygon b. ends at your last coordinate c. does not include your last line
4. clear
5. moveTo your penultimate coordinate, lineTo your last coordinate and then proceed with lineTo calls to draw the

The snippet below is a proof-of-concept that is a good starting point, but it is not a proper solution yet.

```js
const image = document.getElementById("pic");

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//draw the image on the canvas
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

//get mouse coordinates
let coordinates = [];
canvas.onclick = function clickEvent(e)
{
  let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  let y = e.clientY - rect.top;

  let point = {
    "x": x,
    "y": y
  };
  coordinates.push(point);

  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
}

//debugging
console.log(coordinates);

//crop the image
function crop()
{
  ctx.beginPath();

  for(let i=0; i<coordinates.length - 1; i++)
  {
    ctx.lineTo(coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y);
  }
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, canvas.height);
  ctx.lineTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.clip();

  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.restore();
}

function save()
{
  let newCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');

  //get new dimensions
  let top = canvas.height;
  let left = canvas.width;
  let right = -canvas.width;
  let bottom = -canvas.height;
  for(let i=0; i<coordinates.length; i++)
  {
    if(coordinates[i].y < top)
      top = coordinates[i].y;
    if(coordinates[i].x < left)
      left = coordinates[i].x;
    if(coordinates[i].x > right)
      right = coordinates[i].x;
    if(coordinates[i].y > bottom)
      bottom = coordinates[i].y;
  }

  newCanvas.width = right-left;
  newCanvas.height = bottom-top;

  //save the new image
  newCanvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(canvas, left, top, newCanvas.width, newCanvas.height, 0, 0, newCanvas.width, newCanvas.height);

  let downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = "crop.png";
  downloadLink.href = newCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  downloadLink.click();
}
```

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.image-div img {
  max-width: 80vmin;
  max-height: 80vmin;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.canvas-div {
  margin-top: 240px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Image:</h1>
    <div class="image-div">
      <img id="pic" src="https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/07/Helping-your-new-cat-or-kitten-settle-in-1.png">
    </div>

    <div class="canvas-div">
      <h1>Canvas:</h1>
      <canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid blue;"></canvas>
    </div>

    <!-- for exporting the final result -->
    <canvas id="canvas2" style="display: none;"></canvas>

    <button onclick="crop()">Crop</button>
    <button onclick="save()">Save</button>
    <br><br><br>

    <!-- script -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]